# Contact List Permission

Tags: permissions, team-sites, contacts

I was asked to facilitate creating a SINGLE contact list for the entire sales department. However, each division within the sales department, (e.g. Produce, Meat, Daily, etc...) should only be able to view their own specific contacts.

The head of the sales department wants to see all contacts.

Is this possible or will I need separate list under the Sales Department site?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible if you set item-level security for each contact.

But I'd recommend to create separate lists, and then merging items on UI level. Data View Web Part + fine-grained permissions on each list (*ParticularDivision=Read;DepartmentHead=Read*) will result in the behavior you want. Could be done [in SPD](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2012/05/11/how-to-link-two-lists-and-create-a-combined-view-in-sharepoint-2010-aspx/).

Comment: Sure, you'll need to use a workflow (http://johnliu.net/blog/2010/7/13/sharepoint-2010-configuring-list-item-permissions-with-workf.html) or powershell script